# Group by, but transform value element concisely

Tags: java, group-by, java-stream

Given this grouping code:

```
List<Input> inputs = getInputs();
Map<LocalDateTime, List<Input>> inputsByDate =
   inputs.stream()
      .collect(
         groupingBy(input -> input.getDateTime()));
```

What's a succinct way to change that so we can output for each map key a `List<Output>`, where we run each input through a function with signature `private Output convertToOutput(Input input) {}`?

An important note is that the `Output` class does not have the `getDateTime` method, so that has to be performed first, but we don't want the untransformed objects, we want the transformed ones.

In C# Linq-To-Objects it would be easy because the `GroupBy` method gives you `Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector` so you can transform the value portion. How can this easily be done in Java without a lot of custom code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Collectors.mapping`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-):

```
// ...
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        input -> input.getDateTime()),
        Collectors.mapping(    // <--- This
            TheClass::convertToOutput,
            Collectors.toList());
```